# Bootstrap carousel is making steps of 2 instead of 1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My carousel with Bootstrap is skipping an image and I cant find out why. Basically it goes from image 1 to image 3, then it goes to image 2 and from there it skips back to image 1 and repeats the cycle. Can some one please help me?

Code of the carousel:

```
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "container col-xs-6">
            <div id = "banners" class="carousel-slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class = "carousel-inner">
                    <ol class = "carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target = "#banners" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active"></li>
                        <li data-target = "#banners" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
                        <li data-target = "#banners" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class = "item active">
                        <img id = "banners" src = 'images\slide5.jpg' class = "img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "item">
                        <img id = "banners" src = 'images\slide4.jpg' class = "img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "item">
                        <img id = "banners" src = 'images\slide3.jpg' class = "img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                         $('.banners').carousel({
                             interval: 2000
                         })
                    });    
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Quick edit: I also just noticed the indicators dont react on mouse-clicks anymore, how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML structure has some of the components out of place or classes/IDs that are incorrect:

1) `class="carousel-slide"` should be `class="carousel slide"` (not hyphenated)

2) This div `<div class="carousel-inner">` should be place after your `indicators` and before your first `item`.

**Other structural considerations :**

1) You use `id="banners"` four different times, ID's should only be used once. See [explanation](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

2) You are using `<div class="container"> <div class="container col-xs-6">` which isn't of any advantage and the framework actually works like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
```

3) You don't need `class="img-responsive"`.

4) Using the **xs** (`class="col-xs-6"`) column class will most likely reduce your Carousel to an exceedingly small size.

5) You can use `data-interval="2000"` (or your JS) to change your slide speed (this is simply informational as it's just easier if all you care about is the speed)

See working example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="banners" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#banners" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#banners" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#banners" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src='http://placehold.it/1350x550/f00/fff?text=Slide 1' />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src='http://placehold.it/1350x550/000/fff?text=Slide 2' />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src='http://placehold.it/1350x550/ff0/fff?text=Slide 3' />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>XS Column Class: Resize your brower to see the difference.</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div id="banners3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#banners3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#banners3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#banners3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src='http://placehold.it/1350x550/000/fff?text=Slide 1' />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src='http://placehold.it/1350x550/f00/fff?text=Slide 1' />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src='http://placehold.it/1350x550/f00/fff?text=Slide 1' />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried #1 and it immediatly solved the problem, ty.